# Closing secondary window when main window is closed in Python Gtk3

Tags: python, gtk

I have GUI application where I am generating secondary Gtk window on the button clicked on the main window. After the secondary window appears if the user clicked the close button and then window hides. Now what I want to do is: close the secondary window when the user closes the main window.

```py
class GenerateClicked(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Generated BOM")
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_default_size(900, 1000)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ALWAYS)

        # box_pass = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=5)
        renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()

        column_tag = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Tags", renderer_text, text=0)
        bom_tree_view.append_column(column_tag)

        column_location = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Location", renderer_text, text=1)
        bom_tree_view.append_column(column_location)

        column_Enumber = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Part Number", renderer_text, text=2)
        bom_tree_view.append_column(column_Enumber)

        column_cost = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Cost", renderer_text, text=3)
        bom_tree_view.append_column(column_cost)

        column_qty = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Quantity", renderer_text, text=4)
        bom_tree_view.append_column(column_qty)

        column_catalog = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Catalogue", renderer_text, text=5)
        bom_tree_view.append_column(column_catalog)

        column_mfg = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Manufacturer", renderer_text, text=6)
        bom_tree_view.append_column(column_mfg)

        column_desc = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Description", renderer_text, text=7)
        bom_tree_view.append_column(column_desc)

        self.scrolled = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scrolled.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC, Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)
        self.scrolled.add(bom_tree_view)
        self.add(self.scrolled)

        self.connect("delete-event", self.hide_window)
        self.show_all()
        Gtk.main_quit()
        Gtk.main()
```

Comment: This questeion is liable to downvotes and being put on hold because you showed no code that creates your GUI. Hence, the question seems too broad.

Comment: Basically you need to intercept delete-event from main window and override it with your own function which will close both windows. I assume you're using python so this question may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134854/how-to-override-delete-event-in-pygtk/10147391

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help.